# How to filter values when mapping list to dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I am trying to map two list to dictionary, but I am getting err "an object with the same key already exists in ..."

```
List<string> columnValue = new List<string>(); 
List<string> xpathValue = new List<string>();

var dic = columnValue.Zip(xpathValue, (k, v) => new { k, v}).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

Does anyone know how to solve this..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` looks over whole object, so all properties have to be the same to consider objects as equal. Where your list after `Zip` has two elements with the same `k` but difference `v` there will be an error with `ToDictionary`.

Try that one:

```
var dic = columnValue.Zip(xpathValue, (k, v) => new { k, v})
                     .GroupBy(x => x.k)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().v);
```

It's grouping elements by `k`, and adds to dictionary `v` of first element within each group. That solves your problem of `Distinct` method usage.